# Does python garbage collector collects objects with cyclic allocations like below?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Will variable "a" be garbage collected by python garbage collector?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [a,a]
a.append(b)
```

If yes, then what happens if we change value of a dynamically? And how does "b" works if the a has been garbage collected? As per my understanding, the reference to a is lost. Does "b" keeps a new copy itself while the initialisation?

I am trying to understand the garbage collection mechanism in python.
I read in a blog post that in above code, "a" will get collected by the garbage collector as it is a cycle detection case.

Comment: You can read about the GC's design in the official dev docs: https://devguide.python.org/internals/garbage-collector/

Comment: yes, there is an auxiliary [cyclic garbage collector](https://devguide.python.org/internals/garbage-collector/#identifying-reference-cycles) which works on top of the standard reference counting. This will only run on object cycles that **are unreachable**. There are two live references here, so this cycle would never be garbage collected (assuming this is in the global scope)

Comment: Variables themselves are not garbage collected, instead they are each in a scope and are deleted when the scope ends. Values, however, *are* subject to gc (like your value `[1,2,3]`). You need a better example because both `a` and `b` are in the same scope and will hold their references for the same amount of time.

Comment: Also, it is important to understand **variables** are not garbage collected. **Objects** are. Variables are simply references to objects.

Comment: Be sure to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html to understand how the references work.

Comment: I will go through the docs provided in the comments here for a better understanding of the GC. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `a = [1,2,3]; b = [a, a]`, the references look like this:

```
  a -----------------------> 
           +--------------->   [1, 2, 3]
           |  +------------>
           |  |
  b --> [  *, *  ]
```

Namely, the first list has three references pointing two it: one held by the name `a`, the other two by the second list. The second list itself has one reference to it, held by `b`.

After `a.append(b)`, there is one new reference added to the first list, which points to the second list.

```
  a -----------------------> 
           +--------------->   [1, 2, 3, *]
           |  +------------>             |
           |  |                          |
  b --> [  *, *  ] <---------------------+
```

Nothing is garbage-collected, because both lists have references. Even if we execute `del a`, nothing will be garbage-collected, because now memory looks like this:

```
           +--------------->   [1, 2, 3, *]
           |  +------------>             |
           |  |                          |
  b --> [  *, *  ] <---------------------+
```

Both lists are reachable: the second via `b`, and the first list via the second.

Now, if we do `del b` as well, *now* we have something like this:

```
           +--------------->   [1, 2, 3, *]
           |  +------------>             |
           |  |                          |
        [  *, *  ] <---------------------+
```

Both lists have references to each other, *but* "we" have no references to either. *Now* the garbage collector would identify this unreachable reference cycle and collect both lists.

Comment: I can understand the reference cycling now. Thank you.